# iOS:How to add a view on searchBar in UISearchDisplayController and I want the view on top of _UISearchDisplayControllerDimmingView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How to add a view on searchBar in UISearchDisplayController and I want the view on top of _UISearchDisplayControllerDimmingView?

I add the view by `[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar insertSubview:view3 atIndex:0];`. But it was under `_UISearchDisplayControllerDimmingView`.

I show U the pic:
[image: this red view was my view]

If someway to dismiss the `_UISearchDisplayControllerDimmingView` will help me also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want it on the top of dimView put your view on the window of Application.

```
UIView *view = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]windows]objectAtIndex:0];
```

and add your view as subview.

Comment: Thx,U resolved my problem, but there is a small issue with your answer, which is "UIView *dim_view = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];"

Comment: The real question is this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199934/iosi-wanner-to-realize-this-search-function-bellow-and-how-to-do